# How to compress a series of java.awt.image.BufferedImages(TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) to a video(avi,mp4 or other formats can be played by common player)

Tags: java, swing, video, awt

I've already got a series `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`s which are in type of `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`.

I want to compress them into a video stored on the disk. I've searched some solutions on the internet and how can I make it besides Xuggle? GPL and LGPL does not suits my situation.

Comment: What's wrong with using `Xuggle`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Thanks for your attention and it's for the reason of license.

Comment: If the license is relevant, it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson , Thanks and edit has been added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found all these tutorial code under Creative Commons Attribution License on this guy's [blog](http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2008/06/writing-quicktime-videos-in-pure-java/).

[QuickTime Tutorial](https://github.com/attdevsupport/ARO/blob/master/ARODataAnalyzer/src/com/att/aro/videocapture/QuickTimeOutputStream.java)

[The guy's website](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/)

Hope this helps!